# ANSI to UTF-8 conversion

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding

I would like to know if  :

1. all characters encoded in ANSI (1252) could be converted to UTF-8 without any problem.
2. all characters encoded in UTF-8 couldn't be converted to ANSI (1252) without any problem (example : Ǣ couldn't be converted to ANSI encoding).

Could you confirm for me that it corrects ?

Thanks !

Comment: Yes that's correct. 1252 only supports 251 different characters but Unicode has 100,000~ characters assigned so far and room for 1.1 million.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, all characters representable in Windows-1252 have Unicode equivalents, and can therefore be converted to UTF-8. See [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_1252) for a table showing the mapping to Unicode code points.

And since Windows-1252 is an 8-bit character set, and UTF-8 can represent many thousands of distinct characters, there are obviously plenty of characters representable as UTF-8 and not representable as Windows-1252.

Note that the name "ANSI" for the Windows-1252 encoding is strictly incorrect. When it was first proposed, it was intended to be an ANSI standard, but that never happened. Unfortunately, the name stuck. (Microsoft-related documentation also commonly refers to UTF-16 as "Unicode", another misnomer; UTF-16 is one representation of Unicode, but there are others.)